# Extra Foreign Key in Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm kinda new to Entity Framework and Code First Migration so I hope this is an easy question to answer. I am trying to create a one to one relationship between ApplicationUser (from ASP.NET identity) and Member. I have a Member class:

```
public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; } 
}
```

and an ApplicationUserClass:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {

        }       

        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

    }
```

In my DBContext (inherits IdentityDbContext)I have the following configuration:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasOptional(t => t.Member).WithOptionalPrincipal();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

When I run the code first migration, I'm getting this:

```
 CreateTable(
            "dbo.Members",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                    LastName = c.String(),
                    Status = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CreateDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ApplicationUserID = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    Address_ID = c.Int(),
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", t => t.Address_ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ApplicationUserID)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUserID)
            .Index(t => t.Address_ID)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id);
```

Notice that I have 2 foreign keys, **ApplicationUserID** and **ApplicationUser_Id**. I want to try to do everything using FluentAPI (i.e. not Data Annotations). How would I configure it so that EF uses ApplicationUserID, the string ID I have in my class? I thought that Class+ID was the convention, so why is it creating another foreign key?

Comment: Can you add modelBuilder configuration code for your Member class to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should update your configuration this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationUserID);
```

This is the way EntityFramework treats one-to-one relationships, you have to map it that way and introduce `UNIQUE` constraints over your DB table.

More information about this case is here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations

Here's the quote from the link:

> The reason is simple: Code First (and EF in general) does not natively
>   support one-to-one foreign key associations. In fact, EF does not
>   support any association scenario that involves unique constraints at
>   all. Fortunately, in this case we don’t care what’s on the target side
>   of the association, so we can treat it like a to-one association
>   without the many part. All we want is to express “This entity (User)
>   has a property that is a reference to an instance of another entity
>   (Address)” and use a foreign key field to represent that relationship.
>   Basically EF still thinks that the relationship is many-to-one. This
>   is a workaround for the current EF limitation which comes with two
>   consequences: First, EF won't create any additional constraint for us
>   to enforces this relationship as a one to one, we need to manually
>   create it ourselves. The second limitation that this lack of support
>   impose to us is more important: one to one foreign key associations
>   cannot be bidirectional (i.e. we cannot define a User property on the
>   Address class).

Comment: What's weird is I changed it to ApplicationUser_Id and it created ApplicationUser_Id and ApplicationUser_Id1.....